# Angular - HTML element not found in directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to create a pie chart on an element using the directive in Angular 5.  I created a directive like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[pieChart]'
})
export class PieChartDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() pieChart: any;
  @Input() pieChartElementId: string;
  @Input() pieChartData: any;

  constructor(elem: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.generatePieChart(this.pieChartElementId);
  }

  generatePieChart(elemId) {
    var values = [1, 2, 3];

    $('#' + elemId).sparkline(values, {
      type: "pie",

      tooltipFormat: '{{offset:offset}} ({{percent.1}}%)',
      tooltipValueLookups: {
        'offset': {
          0: 'First',
          1: 'Second',
          2: 'Third'
        }
      },
    });
  }
}
```

In the template I'm calling directive like:

```
<div class="pieChartDiv" [attr.id]="'classroom.field1' + '_'+ i" [pieChart]="'classroom.field1' + '_'+ i" [pieChartElementId]="'classroom.field1' + '_'+ i"></div>
```

I'm creating `id` dynamically and want to draw the pie chart on each id. But unfortunately, I'm not getting the length of element in directive when using `console.log($("#"+this.pieChartElementId).length)` in the directive file. Due to that charts are not working because they are not getting the element. Could anyone please tell me why this happening. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of doing `$('#' + elemId)` try `$(this.elem.nativeElement)`. For this to work you will also have to add an access modifier to the `elem` parameter for your constructor to automatically make it a property of your class e.g. `constructor(private elem:ElementRef, renderer:Renderer2) {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use JQuery #() selector with Angular: as you can see, even after view init your pieChartElementId element might not be rendered yet.

Instead you should use `elementRef` or `@ViewChild`:

- If `pieChartElementId` is the element on which `pieChart` directive is applied, you should use:

  `elementRef.nativeElement`
- If you want to select another element, it's a little more complexe. You have to use `@ViewChild` to get the element:

  `@ViewChild('pieChartElement')
   pieChartElement;`

  then pass it to the directive input:

  `<div pieChart [externalElement]="pieChartElement">
    Element with directive
  </div>
  <p #pieChartElement>
    External element
  </p>`

See this [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-playground-hjh6gu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: great explanation.